# Kivy Pong Game Translation

Tags: python, kivy

Just started learning Kivy. The Kivy package I downloaded has several examples for me to start with. However, I had difficulty understanding it because most of it is written with the help of kvlang (file.kv). I did went through the [Kv tutorial](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html), and I still don't understand.

I have some decent experience with Python. But I just can't relate the Kv examples to Python. 
Below is part of a code extracted from the Pong Game in Kivy tutorial.

```
<PongGame>:    
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70  
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.top - 50
        text: "0"
```

Can someone out there help me translate the kv code above in Python form?

Btw is there any other tutorial out there on Kivy language? Because learning Kvlang is still the better way to go in the long term.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your goal exactly? To write up a pong game in python, to learn kivy by relating it to python code, something else?

Comment: Hi Marius. Sort of. To write pong game in Python. And from doing so, I hope I might understand Kivy language better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kivy language is way easier but anyway I hope this helps you. The trick is do all the imports. Particularly important is the `Window` import because you don't have access to the `root` outside of the Kivy Language code.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle

class PongGame(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        label = Label(text = "0")
        label.font_size = 70  
        label.center_x = Window.width / 4
        label.top = Window.height - 50
        self.add_widget(label)

        with self.canvas:
            Rectangle(pos = (Window.width/2 - 5, 0), size = (10,Window.height))

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

Comment: @oneace, if it is the answer, mark it as so...